# Result table is not updated by my python code- though it runs

Tags: python

So I’m currently working on a school project and I’m stuck on the results and would be so thankful if one of you could help me.
The code below seems to be working, however for some reason, it does not seem to return the right output.

Let me try to explain the goal of the project.
Basically, the objective is to evaluate an investment strategy (using Yahoo Finance data). The strategy is the following one :

- we get the daily returns for a period of time
- then, we define a volatility threshold, which is the first decile of the ordered absolute returns of the first 5 years of my period.
- then for the following years (so +5 y), if the return in t-1 < threshold, we buy the stock at price Open in t, update the portfolio value (+Open in t); otherwise (if high volatility), we don’t invest for 10 days and we empty the portfolio (so it gets back to 0)

Shorting positions are not allowed, and I need to print the processus of buying and selling by saying “Opening the position”/“Closing the position” each time it happens;

At the end of the period, I want to look at the profit of the strategy.

Below the code is a screenshot of my results, which are not coherent at all. I don’t get how come the position remains at 0 all the time, same for ptf_val (which the value of the portfolio)…

```
import pandas_datareader.data as data
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class InvestissementStrategie:
    #Instantiate the object
    def __init__(self, stock_name, start_date, end_date):
        self.stock_name = stock_name
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date
        self.all_quotes = self.fetch_data()
        self.threshold = self.calculate_threshold()

    #This function fetch the data needed on Yahoo Finance
    def fetch_data(self):
        #Fix the yahoo finance comptability issues
        yf.pdr_override()
        #Fetch data and return them
        return data.get_data_yahoo(self.stock_name, start=self.start_date, end=self.end_date)

    #This function calculate the threshold of high volatility
    def calculate_threshold(self):
        five_years = self.all_quotes.iloc[:5*252] # There are 252 trading days in one year
        # Calculate the difference between the two dates
        delta = self.end_date - self.start_date

        # Check if the difference is less than 5 years
        if delta.days < 365*5:
            print("The period is too short")

        # Get absolute daily returns for the first 5 years and sort them in descending order
        returns = five_years['Adj Close'].pct_change().abs().dropna()
        sorted_returns = returns.abs().sort_values(ascending=False)

        # Calculate the threshold
        threshold = np.percentile(sorted_returns, 90)
        return threshold

    #This function calculate the profit of the trading strategy
    def apply_strategy(self):
        self.all_quotes['returns'] = self.all_quotes['Adj Close'].pct_change()
        self.all_quotes['position'] = 0
        self.all_quotes['ptf_val'] = np.nan
        self.all_quotes['strategy'] = np.nan
        self.all_quotes['cumulative'] = np.nan

        days_counter = 0
        ptf_val = 0

        #the trading strategy is for the following years (after 5 years)
        index_pos = 5*252  # set the starting index position
        while index_pos < len(self.all_quotes):
            if abs(self.all_quotes.iloc[index_pos-1]['returns']) < self.threshold:
                self.all_quotes.at[self.all_quotes.index[index_pos], 'ptf_val'] = self.all_quotes.at[self.all_quotes.index[index_pos-1], 'ptf_val'] + self.all_quotes.iloc[index_pos]['Open']
                self.all_quotes.at[self.all_quotes.index[index_pos], 'position'] = 1
                index_pos += 1  # increment the index position by 1

            else:
                self.all_quotes.at[self.all_quotes.index[index_pos], 'ptf_val'] = ptf_val
                self.all_quotes.at[self.all_quotes.index[index_pos], 'position'] = - 1
                index_pos += 10  # increment the index position by 10

       

        self.all_quotes['ptf_val'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
        self.all_quotes['position'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

        self.all_quotes['strategy'] = self.all_quotes['returns'] * self.all_quotes['position']
        self.all_quotes['cumulative'] = (1 + self.all_quotes['strategy']).cumprod()

        profit = self.all_quotes['cumulative'][-1] - 1


        print('strategy P/L  : {:.2f}'.format(profit))
        print(self.all_quotes)

        return profit


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Data variables
    stock_name = 'AAPL'
    start_date = dt.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
    end_date = dt.datetime(2022, 12, 31)

    strategie = InvestissementStrategie(stock_name, start_date, end_date)
    threshold = strategie.calculate_threshold()
    profit = strategie.apply_strategy()
    print("Threshold is:", threshold)
    print("Profit de la stratégie : {:.2%}".format(profit))
```

Here are the results I obtain :

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8TLl.png)

Also, it is a school requirement that I use classes and objects.
Thanks a lot if you have any answers or comments which could help me move forward!

PS : my deadline is tonight

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/354577) (TL;DR: It's never okay.)

Comment: Did your professor specify what they wanted you to use classes for? A stock return is just the difference between two endpoints: date2 return - date1 return.